# SELECT comment FROM comments_by_video WHERE uuid = 'with id 357c33b4-9054-a5e1- 8da8-d9e38294fac1';

Tags: cassandra

I create table with

```
CREATE TABLE comments_by_video (
videoid uuid,
userid uuid,
comment text, 
PRIMARY KEY(videoid, commentid));
```

and copy the table.

I excuted this query below

```
SELECT comment FROM comments_by_video WHERE userid = 'with id 357c33b4-9054-a5e1- 8da8-d9e38294fac1';
```

and got this error.

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (with id 357c33b4-9054-a5e1- 8da8-d9e38294fac1) for "userid" of type uuid"
```

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

First error - UUIDs are written as-is, without quotes: `357c33b4-9054-a5e1- 8da8-d9e38294fac1`

Second error - you're having condition on the field that isn't a partition key - this will require full table scan and won't work at scale.  In Cassandra table structure is modeled around queries, so you'll need to have a table with partition key for userid

I recommend to read [first chapters of this free book](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide) to understand how Cassandra works.

Comment: Hi, I added this comments cqlsh:name> SELECT comment FROM comments_by_user WHERE userid = 357c33b4-9054-a5e1- 8da8-d9e38294fac1; AND GOT THIS RESULT
SyntaxException: line 1:71 mismatched character ' ' expecting set null

Comment: in comments_by_user table userid is pk

Comment: Remove space before 8da